# Android - RecyclerView notifyItemRemoved not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I add an item for the progressBar at the end for loading more, and when load finish, I remove this item before adding element at the end of adapter.
But the the item is not correctly removed.

```
if (arrayAdapter != null) {
        arrayAdapter.list.add(null);
        arrayAdapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        arrayAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(arrayAdapter.getItemCount(), arrayAdapter.getItemCount());
    }
    serverRequests.getQuestionsAnsweredInBackground(userID, type, startLoad, new GetQuestionCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void done(ArrayList<Question> questions) {
            if (arrayAdapter != null) {
                arrayAdapter.list.remove(arrayAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                arrayAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(arrayAdapter.getItemCount());
                arrayAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(arrayAdapter.getItemCount(), arrayAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
            if (questions != null) {
                if (arrayAdapter == null) {
                    arrayAdapter = new QuestionsAnsweredAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_questions_answered_item, questions, QuestionsAnswered.this);
                    lvQuestionsAnswered.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    listLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    final int positionStart = arrayAdapter.getItemCount();
                    arrayAdapter.list.addAll(questions);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, questions.size());
                }
                startLoad += questions.size();
                loading = true;
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bug or i make an error somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Before loading new data

```
if(!mIsloading)
{
  arrayAdapter.list.add(null);
  arrayAdapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayAdapter.list.size() - 1);
  mIsloading = true; 
}
```

After done with fetching data

```
serverRequests.getQuestionsAnsweredInBackground(userID, type, startLoad, new GetQuestionCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void done(ArrayList<Question> questions) {
           if (arrayAdapter.list.size() > 0 && arrayAdapter.list.get(arrayAdapter.list.size() - 1) == null) {
                    arrayAdapter.list.remove(arrayAdapter.list.size() - 1);
                    arrayAdapter.list.notifyItemRemoved(arrayAdapter.list.size());
                }
          mIsloading = false;   
            }
```